# Views data export user role field value missing from exported csv file

Tags: views, 8, importing-exporting, batch-operations

I'm using [views_data_export](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_data_export) to export data from the views displays. I added a **Data Export** option to the user account list views. When I use the **batch** in export settings, user role field is missing in the exported CSV file. While not using batch, role field is there.

[image]

Thanks

Comment: have you tried the export without the exposed filters?

Comment: yes I did, it doesn't make any difference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found this is a bug in the module itself, and the following patch will solve the issue.

Discussion: https://www.drupal.org/project/views_data_export/issues/2789531#comment-13345278

Patch: https://www.drupal.org/files/issues/2019-11-08/views_data_export_batch_empty_fields.patch